# How read input file from the user and generate all tokens in output and as well as invalid tokens mention?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to make a java program that accept the input from the file provided by the user. 
The scanner will then scan the java code file and identifies all
 the tokens and list them as the output for user. 
In case of an invalid token, Scanner should mention that a given token is invalid...
Here is my code ,I m working in netbeans.

```
    package javaapplication3;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
     /**
    *
    * @author Hameed
     */
 public class JavaApplication3 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,       IOException {
  FileReader fin = new FileReader("myfile.java");
   Open(fin);
   BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fin);
    String s;
    s=br.readLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "[ =+';().*{}[],!@#$%^&/]", true);
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

but when i run the error occur,here is image http://s17.postimg.org/jlj18yefj/Untitled.jpg
implement code in scanner,and myfile.java is in JavaApplication3 folder,is it right if not then kindly guide me where is store this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the working directory,

Right Click on Project > Properties > Run > Working Directory.

Here is where you program search the file.txt.

Comment: This error occur in output   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.Open(JavaApplication3.java:34)
 at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:22)

Comment: here is the output come   run:
49
+
62
*
61-36
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
but myfile.java here http://pastebin.com/aCuvAsFX

Comment: ok, this is another problem. Please check your code. If you don't know well how to read a file -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: My program working run well,but it read just first line in the file,kindly tell me how can read all file and generate tokens

Comment: i correct the file error,,now here is my output ,but there is a bit confusion in output please help me http://s9.postimg.org/x2h6rtztr/Untitled.jpg , why it come 76-50 , i want it dislay

Comment: i want 76-50 76 come in one line then - in other and 50 in next line

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssss alot .Thankss Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

By using `new FileReader("myfile.java")` you are specifying a relative path. In this case, assuming the file is in the classpath, you should do it like:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(JavaApplication3.class.getResourceAsStream("myfile.java"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

Another way to do it is to specify the absolute path to the file when creating the `FileReader`, for instance:

```
FileReader fin = new FileReader("C:\\myfile.java");
```

Comment: I set  file path right now but following error occur in output     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.Open(JavaApplication3.java:34)
 at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:22)

Comment: here is the output come run: 49   + 62 * 61-36 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds) but myfile.java here pastebin.com/aCuvAsFX –

Comment: That exception is being thrown inside your method `Open`. What does that method do? Can you post the code?

Comment: i correct the file error,,now here is my output ,but there is a bit confusion in output please help me s9.postimg.org/x2h6rtztr/Untitled.jpg , why it come 76-50

Comment: i want 76-50 76 come in one line then - in other and 50 in next line

Comment: Thankssssssssssssssssssss alot .Thankss Stackoverflow